# How to force a php script to run until its finished?

Tags: php, linux, server, lamp

Problem:

I have a webserver, which is mostly php and every page is dynamicly created with php. On one page I have a php script, that a user can start, which runs for 2-3 minutes until its finished. The problem here is: The script does not finish, when the user decides to switch pages on the website or does anything else, that starts annother php script.

is there any way to force a php script to run until its finished, even if other php scripts are started?

Comment: If the user stays on that page, do you care about the PHP output to the browser? In other words, when the script finishes, does it report something the user needs to see?

Comment: This might be useful: https://chuniversiteit.nl/flat-earth/blursed-async-php

Comment: Make the user-started script simply write a row to a DB table. Then have a cron job or daemon running which regularly checks the table for new rows, and then runs the requested task. If you need to give some feedback to the user when it's done, there are a few possible ways, depending on your requirements. But presumably if these users are regularly clicking away then perhaps they don't really care about the results? Or maybe they just get bored because no-one expects a web page to take 3 minutes to return...so either you need to optimise, or you need to offload as I've described.

Comment: The users do exactly know what the server is doing and usually wait for the script to finish. The annoying thing is, that the users are stuck on this page and cant continue using the site until they see the result. The result of the long running script is a pdf-file, that is opened in a new tab... so the users will always wait for the result, but it would be better if they could to something else on the website in the meanwhile

Comment: They can always open a new tab themselves and carry on working

Comment: Or why not do my suggestion, and then just email them the file at the end? Or email them a link to the file? Or even use websockets to tell them the file is available, if they're still online?

Comment: _"The result of the long running script is a pdf-file, that is opened in a new tab..."_ - you mean, that new tab only gets opened _after_ the long script is done creating the PDF? Why don't you open it _before_ then? User requests PDF -> you open new tab, that request starts the PDF generating script. The user can switch back to the original tab, and keep on navigating the site ...

Comment: Now that we know it's about generating a PDF the question makes more sense. What I see often, and which I like, is that you can request a PDF to be generated. It is then generated in the background, and when it is finished it presents a download/open link.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution built into PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

You can simply call this:

`ignore_user_abort(true);`

This `ignore_user_abort` setting is also one which you can apply using the php.ini or .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ignore_user_abort**, more info found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: it builds string with data from a mysql-db and returns a pdf-file to the user when its finished. when the user does anything else while the script is running, the script wont return anything

Comment: @changepicture you simply can not get a response from your script back to the user, if the user navigated elsewhere in the meantime. Letting your script finish, is a completely different issue, than whether there is still a client around who is actually waiting for a response.